# Reshaping data in pandas dataframe with two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

Consider this sample data:

```
    ID     Name      question     comment
0   123    Smith     question A   good 
1   123    Smith     question B   bad 
2   444    Jones     question C   bad 
3   444    Jones     question A   good 
4   333    Williams  Question B   bad
```

Tried pivot and pivottable (some kind of unmelting) to try and get this ideal reshaping:

```
        ID     Name      question A  question B  quesetion C
    0   123    Smith     good        bad         null
    1   444    Jones     good        null        bad
    2   333    Williams  null        bad         null
```

This did not work:

```
 pd.pivot_table(data, values = 'comment', index=['ID','Name'], columns = 'question').reset_index()
```

I am sure there is some detail within the pivot or pivottable functions I am missing, so it's close.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You data is not numeric, either pass `aggfunc='first'` or use `df.pivot(values = 'comment', index=['ID','Name'], columns = 'question').reset_index()`

Comment: How would I pass aggfunc='first' in this context?

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(...., aggfunc='first')`?

Comment: I will try that.  The first option threw this error, which I recall seeing before.  'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: That means some user with `id,name` answer some question twice. `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='first'` will retain just the first answer. If you want to keep all answer, you need to enumerate rows with same pair `id,name`

Comment: The aggfunc='first' worked it seems.  Thanks so much!